# Is there a way to create a system keyboard app for iOS/Android using JS and CSS?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

I am trying to build my own custom system keyboard app for iOS/Android but I would like to use JS/CSS instead of Java or swift.

Are there other ways to achieve this? (cordova/ionic)
Basically all I need is to be able to register a new system keyboard somehow.

Answer (score 2):

On iOS it is not possible because the keyboard is a native system function, an ionic app is just a wrapper of a native app with a web view that allows you to run your web app locally and due to the behavior of the keyboard your app would have to be loaded on top of other apps and as you may know, this is not possible on iOS.